# am running locally on the Google App Engine, but i run it to GAE I just get this error:

Tags: php, google-app-engine, joomla, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
Warning: ini_set(): Cannot find save handler 'files' in 
C:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\CloudNow\new\test\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 100
```

the 100th line is: `ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');`

and one more fatal error like,

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 
bytes) in C:\Users\Senni\Desktop\CloudNow\new\test\libraries\joomla\language\language.php on
 line 174
```

the 174th line is :`$this->setLanguage($lang);`

Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, i posted the question wrongly. the actual question is,         am running joomla locally on the Google App Engine, but i get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine doesn't allow writing to local filesystem (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_The_sandbox), so setting session.save_handler to "files" won't work. There's a built-in session handler based on Memcache, which you can enable by manually setting session.save_handler to "user", or rely on the default value (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Sessions)